# create multiple text file and write to it

Tags: c#

I want to create 100 files to the destination folder, below are the source code however it create file in the destination folder. Appreciate any help

```
 class Program
{
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        int i=1;
        string path = @"E:\Project\C_Sharp\Tutorial\Console_App\FileSystem\Output\";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string FileName = "MyTest" + i + ".txt";
                path = FileName;
                // Create a file to write to. 
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                    sw.WriteLine("And");
                    sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
                }

            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You are getting errors? Exceptions? Something else? Did you debug through your code to see where it is not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotem got this pretty well, but I wanted to add on what the code should look like.

```
string path = @"E:\Project\C_Sharp\Tutorial\Console_App\FileSystem\Output\";
if (!File.Exists(path))
```

You're both checking a directory, and you want to do this if it DOES exist. You want

```
if (Directory.Exists(path)
```

Then you're reassigning your directory path to your filename

```
string FileName = "MyTest" + i + ".txt";
path = FileName;
```

What you want to do is concatenate (combine) the two strings

```
string FilePath = path + @"MyTest" + i.ToString() + ".txt"
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(FilePath))
```

This way you don't overwrite your path value every time you go through the loop.

Comment: I would also get in the habit of using `Path.Combine` for path concatenations instead of `+`. It prevents me from making stupid mistakes at least once a day.

Comment: @Rotem Oh cool, I didn't know about that. At work I generally have to work in .NET 3.5, and it looks like `Path.Combine` is only in 4 and up, but I'll definitely remember this.

Comment: @cost Actually it's from v1.0

Comment: @Rotem Really? I just assumed it was 4.0 and up since the MSDN article for it only has 4 and 4.5 listed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx Nice to hear though

Comment: @cost That only refers to the version of the documentation page that lists the overloads, msdn was organized differently in previous versions. If you select one of the overloads and scroll to the bottom it will list all supported versions of the method.

Comment: @Rotem It looks like they show the highest common denominator. I see now that `Path.Combine(string, string) has existed since 1.0, but the other three overloads were more recent additions.

Answer (score 3):

I see at least 3 things wrong.

1. `if (!File.Exists(path))` - `path` is a `Directory`, not a `File`.
2. You want to enter the loop if the directory **does** exist, not if it doesn't exist. It makes no sense otherwise.
3. `path = Filename;` - you want to concatenate the two strings to a new variable, not overwrite `path`.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-setting the path

```
path = FileName;
```

You shoud concat the FileName to Path and use `File.Exists`

```
        int i=1;
        string path = @"E:\Project\C_Sharp\Tutorial\Console_App\FileSystem\Output\";
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string FileName = "MyTest" + i + ".txt";
                var newpath= path + FileName;
                // Create a file to write to. 
                if(!File.Exists(newpath)){
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                    sw.WriteLine("And");
                    sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
                }}

            }
        }
```

Comment: You still have `path` in `File.CreateText` and you probably want `if (!File.Exists(newpath)`